# The "Zend Framework Problem" question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, google, seo

I've noticed that ["session has already been started...." exception in Zend Framework application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418124/zend-framework-problem) has 4k views. It's about exception thrown from `Zend_Session`. I **guess** a lot of traffic comes from Google, searching for any (other) Zend framework problem, and not for the session explicitly.

Maybe we can make the question an index to commonly asked Zend framework problems (with the help of the ones that actually answer them).

Or maybe we have to rename the question, hence change the URL. I'm not sure what will happen with the Google indexing and traffic trough.

What do you think?

Comment: A more general question would be something along the lines of "What to do with crappy questions that have vague enough title to attract tons of misled Google visitors". I've actually seen this with [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery) (see how poor the question was [originally](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/582268/1))

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question should most certainly not be completely rewritten to turn it into an index for Zend questions - doing so is pretty much against what editing is for, and is problematic for a ton of other reasons, from everything to reputation to ownership of questions.

Editing the title to better reflect the question would be a much better choice, even if you're sacrificing some Google traffic. Those visitors probably won't leave with a good impression of Stack Overflow if they find such poor question on the site anyway. However, before doing that, it might be a good idea to have a mod check the analytic and anonymous feedback data to see if the visitors are benefiting from the question. I would suggest cleaning up the question's body in any case - it's a pretty poorly asked question.

Comment: Looks like Pekka came in and did the retitle.

Answer (score 7):

I seriously doubt the title was driving traffic; the question is about (what is most likely) a very common error, including the error's message and stack trace.  [If you google the exception message](http://www.google.com/search?q=Fatal+error%3A+Uncaught+exception+%27Zend_Session_Exception%27+with+message+%27session+has+already+been+started+by+session.auto-start+or+session_start) you'll see that its the first hit.  You'll also find a number of dupes as well...